# How to compute the angular momentum at some point based on the angular momentum at the center of mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, reference-frames, rotational-dynamics

Can you explain what is the third vector (the one with the tag) in the following equation: 
\begin{align}
\vec{L} = \vec{L}_{\text{cm}}+\vec{L}'
\end{align}

Comment: You haven't attached any equation. Also, homework like questions should ask about the specific conceptual issues. Simply posting a question without explaining your approach etc. won't garner good responses.

Comment: Also, don't use images for equations, instead, use the MathJax to produce beautiful equations :)

Comment: It is angular momentum of body w.r.t center of mass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\vec{L}$ is the angular momentum relative to some arbitrary point.

$\vec{L}_\text{cm}$ is the angular momentum of the center of mass relative to that arbitrary point.

$\vec{L}’$ is the angular momentum of the system relative to its center of mass.

In general, angular momentum has a contribution from the motion of the center of mass and a contribution from the motion *around* the center of mass.